# How to apply for several GPUs from different nodes in slurm?

Tags: python, slurm

I want to run my job on 3 GPUs, but I found I can not get 3 GPUs from different nodes.

In `my_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=gpu-long
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-gpu=6
#SBATCH -t 7-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-gpu=90G

idx=0; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=1 &
idx=1; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=2 &
idx=1; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=3 &

wait
```

Sometimes, I can find that there are 3 GPUs availables on different nodes, but my job is still waiting, until 3 GPUs from the same node are available.

Comment: CUDA cannot use GPUs in other nodes, so this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Be more explicit with slurm:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --partition=gpu-long
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-gpu=6
#SBATCH --mem-per-gpu=90G
#SBATCH --gpus-per-node=1
#SBATCH --time 7-00:00:00


idx=0; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=1 &
idx=1; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=2 &
idx=1; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=3 &

wait
```

In this cas, you requests 3 nodes, with each one GPU and RAM and CPU associated.
Slurm give 3 nodes with `TresPerNode=gpu:1,gpu:1` per node.

Seems to be that you want for your job ?